# How to map two filtered lists with the operator 'and' and/or 'or'

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have following two lists:

```
advanced_filtered_list_val1 = [row for row in cleaned_list if float(row[val1]) < wert1]

advanced_filtered_list_val2 = [row for row in cleaned_list if float(row[val2]) < wert2]
```

How can I map the filtered lists in a list with the option and and/or or?

The data in the lists are dictionaries and I search and filter some rows in this lists. I want to filter two values on. This works fine. But how can I now map this to filter in a list?

I tried following things:

```
select = int(input())

#and operation
if select == 1:
    mapped_list = [row for row in advanced_filtered_list_val1 and advanced_filtered_list_val2]
    for x in mapped_list:
        print(x)
#or operation
if select == 2:
    mapped_list = [row for row in advanced_filtered_list_val1 or advanced_filtered_list_val2]
    for x in mapped_list:
        print(x)
```

I import the data as follows:

```
faelle = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()}


for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")]
```

I want to filter now from `wert1` and `wert2` and from `wert1` or `wert2`. Thats mean on the `and` clause it should be on both filters `true`, and on the `or` clause it should one of `wert1` or `wert2` `True`

Comment: SO the first should be an intersection of the two, the second a union?

Comment: ... or is the first `mapped_list` the list of values that are in the intersection of both lists and the second the set of values that appear in any one of the lists?

Comment: Actually, your question is not really clear. You should consider to reformulate it with a reproducible example, and the expected result. What do you mean by "*How can I map the filtered lists in a list with the option and and/or or?*" ?

Comment: I have edit the OP. I hope it will be clearly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter dictionaries contained in `cleaned_list` which respect either the two `wert`-like conditions (AND) or at least one of them (OR). What you can do is

```
import operator as op
ineq_1    = 'gt'
ineq_2    = 'lt'
select    = 2
andor = {
    1:lambda L: filter(
        lambda d: getattr(op,ineq_1)(float(d[val1]), wert1)
                  and getattr(op,ineq_2)(float(d[val2]), wert2),
        L
    ),
    2:lambda L: filter(
        lambda d: getattr(op,ineq_1)(float(d[val1]), wert1)
                  or getattr(op,ineq_2)(float(d[val2]), wert2),
        L
    ),
}

mapped_list = andor[select](cleaned_list)
for x in mapped_list:
    print(dict(x))
```

The possible choices are `gt` (greater than), `lt` (lower than), or `eq`.

---

Note that you can even make things a little bit more "dynamic" by as well using the method `and_` and `or_` of the python-builtin module [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html). For example, doing

```
#Where the two following ix2-like stuffs are defined to make
# a correspondence between names one knows, and methods of the
#  module operator.
ix2conj = {
    1:'and_',
    2:'or_',
}
ix2ineq = {
    '<' :'lt',
    '==':'eq',
    '>' :'gt',
}
def my_filter(conjunction, inequality1, inequality2, my_cleaned_list):
    return filter(
        lambda d: getattr(op, ix2conj[conjunction])(
                       getattr(op, ix2ineq[inequality1])(float(d[val1]), wert1),
                       getattr(op, ix2ineq[inequality2])(float(d[val2]), wert2)
                       ),
        my_cleaned_list
        )

ineq_1    = '>'
ineq_2    = '<'
select    = 2
print(my_filter(select, ineq_1, ineq_2, cleaned_list))
```

Comment: Assuming both lists contain items, wouldn't `l1 and l2 == l2` and `l1 or l2 == l1`

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: filter() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Comment: @Kanak version 3.5.4

Comment: @madik_atma Do you have something else that you named `filter` in your script ?

Comment: sry. I had a function is named filter. ^^ Now the Error is: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: @madik_atma. it works for me. See the second part of my answer, after the title ***Copy-pastable script***, (*for testing purposes*), test this, and tell me if you still have the same error.

Comment: on the and clause its not work clearly I see. I think on and should be both values filtered True. But now on and only second value is True

Comment: @madik_atma Let's reformulate. You want to filter dictionaries contained in `cleaned_list` which respect either the two `wert`-like conditions (AND) or at least one of them (OR) ? Right ?

Comment: OK.. It works great! But it is my mistake, because I forget it that I have 3 options on my code. <, > and ==. Thats mean your solution works only for <. And I tried also other operators like > and ==. But for < its work! How we can make it so for all this 3 operators? Sry, I forget It It is already so late..

Comment: @madik_atma. And now ? Are your three cases dealt ? :)

Comment: Seems very good, but you can in the code select for the two values two different operators. Like: wert1 > 10 and wert2 == 2. all the possibilities from this operators. It this possible?

Comment: @Kanak I would like to do more than just "right solution". You helped me wonderfully. You are great made!

Comment: @madik_atma. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I see where you're coming from with that syntax, but that's not what the "and" and "or" keywords in python do at all. To do what you're looking for I think you'll want to use the built in type, `set`. You could do something like

```
# note that this is already the "or" one
both = list1 + [x for x in list2 if not x in list1]

# for "and"
mapped_list = [x for x in both if x in list1 and x in list2]
```

If you want the resultant lists to have only unique values; otherwise you could just do the same with

```
both = list1 + list2
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for OP's data. "The data in the lists are dictionaries".  You can't have a `set` of `dict`s, as they are unhashable.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that; I updated my answer with the method that only uses lists.